# Can't return the current date

Tags: php, date

I've made a function to get the current date with a custom date format, this is the code:

```
function getTimestamp($dateFormat)
{
    $dateFormat = "d-m-Y G:i:s.u";
    $originalTime = microtime(true);
    $micro = sprintf("%06d", ($originalTime - floor($originalTime)) * 1000000);
    $date = new DateTime(date('d-m-Y H:i:s.'.$micro, $originalTime));
    echo $date->format($dateFormat);
    return $date->format($dateFormat);
}
```

the date returned is this:

> 05-02-2016 0:28:05.839051

but should be this instead:

> 05-02-2016 0:09:30.839051

what I did wrong?

Comment: the code above is returning current date only, that is 05-02-2016, what else you need?

Comment: @AmitShah yes, return the current date but, in my location Italy the hour returned is wrong: `05-02-2016 0:28:05.839051`, should be returned this: `05-02-2016 0:09:30.839051` instead.

Comment: @AmitShah, I guess its the issue related to the time

Comment: It could be a timezone problem. So, you could try setting **date_default_timezone_set ('Europe/Rome')** (at top of your script, outside the _getTimestamp()_ function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this, it should solve your problem, set locale.

```
    function getTimestamp($dateFormat)
{
    $dateFormat = "d-m-Y G:i:s.u";
    $originalTime = microtime(true);
    $micro = sprintf("%06d", ($originalTime - floor($originalTime)) * 1000000);
    $date = new DateTime(date('d-m-Y H:i:s.'.$micro, $originalTime));
    $date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Rome'));    
    echo $date->format($dateFormat);
    return $date->format($dateFormat);
}
```

did modification to set time zone.

Thanks
Amit

Comment: Nope, your solution return: `05-02-2016 0:41:16.000000`

Comment: can you please use the new code, it will set default time zone and will help you to get what you wanted.

Comment: @Dillinger you are right issue is related to time, and timezone which is ther in php.ini by default.